# Managing delegates with GCD on iOS 5, how to do it?

Tags: multithreading, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I have an object that has a method that returns its results over a delegate method, a couple of seconds later. I understand that if I do this on another thread using GCD I can improve my UI performance, but what about the delegate method that is implemented on the object that is running on the main thread?

So this all happens in the main thread:

On the header file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ThisRespondsToSomeDelegate>
```

On the implementation file of the view controller:

```
SomeObject _myDealer; // INSTANCE VARIABLE OF THE OBJECT THAT IMPLEMENTS THE ThisRespondsToSomeDelegate TYPE
```

Later on the same implementation file:

```
[_myDealer getSomeData];
```

And later, the delegate method:

```
-(void)myDealerReturnedSomeData:data anotherArg:(id)somemoredata {...};
```

From what I understand, I create a *background_queue* object with the *dispatch_queue_create* method and than use:

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) { [_myDealer getSomeData]; });
```

But how do I return to the delegate method on the main thread? How does myDealerReturnedSomeData:data get called?

Thanks!

Happy coding!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. *1.* Which class downloads data and provides a delegate protocol? *2.* Which class implements a delegate protocol? I guess that `MyViewController` implements the delegate protocol, and `SomeObject` is a class that performs a lenghty task and provides a delegate. Common pattern would be that `SomeObject` calls the delegate from its inside (once it finished the task), so `dispatch_async()` would be called inside the implementation of `SomeObject`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a method on a main thread after a background GCD task completes, simply dispatch it in a block to a main queue after your background task completes its execution:

```
// this runs in background
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    [_myDealer getSomeData];

    // once the code above returns you schedule a block on the main queue:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.delegate myDealderReturnedSomeData:[_myDealer someData] anotherArg:...];
    });
});
```

Comment: But the delegate method arguments are generated inside _myDealer instance, more accurately inside getSomeData method, how are the accessible when I call self.dekegate...?

Comment: I edited my answer a bit to show that you can access `_myDealer` freely inside a nested block. It's just called after `getSomeData` returns.

Comment: And what if the argument isn't an instance variable of _mydealer but a variable inside the getSomeData method?

Comment: To me it seems that you would like `_myDealer` (or more precisely - `SomeObject`) class to do some work in background thread by itself. So instead of using GCD in your view controller you'd rather implement your calculations/data fetching/whatever time-consuming operations inside `getSomeData` method and from there you could call a delegate method. How does that sound?